# Can someone explain these jcrop parameters?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I'm currently tearing my hair out with the jquery plugin from DeepLiquid called `jCrop`.

Could someone who has successfully used it please let me know what the following parameters should be set at.

I have a crop area that is `909px x 618px`.

I have a preview area that is `545px x 341px`.

My cropbox code has the following parameters:

```
boxWidth,
boxHeight,
boundx,
boundy,
xsize,
ysize.
```

Could someone let me know which parameter relates to which image (i.e. the image you are cropping OR the preview image). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've spent a happy few hours sorting this out and for anyone who stumbles across this question the answer is:
boxWidth/boxHeight are the dimensions of the div holding the image you want to crop
boundx/boundy are calculated by jcrop and are the actual image dimensions
xsize/ysize is the size (in pixels) of the preview image

As it happened my issue (hence the question) ended up being that I had not included the class of "jcrop-preview" in the img element holding the jcrop preview.

So, there's 8 hours of my life I'll never get back... oh well, onwards and upwards...